# Given tfs name is not correct URI and not found as a registered TFS instance

Tags: cmd, git-tfs

Using git-tfs, when I try and connect to my tfs server I get the error message:

> Given tfs name is not correct URI and not found as a registered TFS instance

The command I'm using is:

> git tfs clone "http://ip.add.re.ss:8080/tfs/Collection Name/" "$/Project Name" "C:\git"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces cause issues when connecting. The way around it is:

> git tfs clone "http://ip.add.re.ss:8080/tfs/Collection%20Name/" $/"Project Name" "C:\git"

i.e:

1. For the collection, use `%20` to replace spaces
2. For the project, put the open quote *after* the `$/` instead of before